# How to get vim syntax highlighting to work?

Tags: vim, opensuse, syntax-highlighting

I cannot get vim syntax highlighting to work on a suse box.

I have (only this two lines) in my `~/.vimrc`

```
filetype plugin on
syntax on
```

If I open a shell script with .sh an do

```
:set filetype?
```

I get

```
filetype=sh
```

Entering

```
:scriptnames
```

gives

```
  1: /etc/vimrc
  2: /usr/share/vim/vim73/syntax/syntax.vim
  3: /usr/share/vim/vim73/filetype.vim
  4: ~/.vimrc
  5: /usr/share/vim/vim73/ftplugin.vim
```

which means my `~/.vimrc` is loaded.

As you can see from the screen shot, the `~` after the end of the file are blue, so there's is some color at least, but no syntax highlighting.
[image]

Any ideas what's wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since I'm on SUSE, installing vim is not enough. I had to install vim-data. Once installed, nothing else needs to be done. Syntax highlighting works out of the box.

To install vim-data, use YaST, or on the command line:

```
zypper install vim-data
```

Comment: When installing vim on Tumbleweed, this should be a dependency. However, it is currently missing, and users will need to devote a significant amount of work to correct this. This response saved me a few days.

Comment: I performed password recovery for SE and logged in just to upvote this.  Haunting me for months